# Exe wont run on windows xp when compiled with visual studio 2013 c++

Tags: c++, windows, boost, visual-studio-2013, static-libraries

I have created an application using c++ Visual Studio 2013 and it wont run under windows xp but runs fine under windows 7. The exe is made up of many static libraries I have written and many 3rd Parties. It uses the following 3rd party libraries

OIS, zlib, zzip, freetype, freeimage, ogre, glsl_optimiser hlsl2glsl, tinyxml, boost.

I have downloaded prebuilt boost version 1_57 for vc12 with static linking to the c/c++ runtime libraries. They are the static library version of boost and doesn't require any boost dlls.

I have compiled the rest of the 3rd party libraries myself. I have set them all to be built as static libraries which link statically to the c/c++ runtime libraries. I have also set the platform toolset to v120_xp to get xp support.

I have made the same changes to all my own static libraries as well as the exe project.

When I run it on an xp machine there is no error dialog. There is not even sign of the exe trying to load, just a whole lot of nothing.

I previously got the "This is not a vaild win32 application" error message before rebuilding everything as v120_xp.

Boost is the only libraries that I have not added this setting to as I have the prebuilt versions.

Any ideas what I can try next or is there something I can check to see why the exe isnt loading?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Install [Update2 for MSVC](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-2013-compatibility-vs.aspx), then re-build everything.

Comment: Do you have [Redistributable C++ files for VS 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784) installed on your target machine?

Comment: I am using Update4 for MSVC2013 and I shouldnt need the redistributables because I have statically linked against them (correct me if I am wrong). Thanks both

Comment: From the description it really seems like you should _not_ need redist files, but there might be some hidden dependency or so which you overlooked, at least thats what usually happens to me :) Should not hurt to give it a try and to see for yourself.

Comment: Have you built the exe file for the proper architecture (i.e. make sure you're not trying to run an x86_64 executable on an x86 machine/OS).

Comment: It is definitely using the correct architecture. As for installing the redistributables I am not allowed to as it is for a 3rd party gaming machine and I can't request that. I can copy the files manually though. I assume you are talking about both msvcp120.dll and msvcr120.dll?